# vb.net client server - connect to desktop app from website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, connection, client-server, client-side

Tools : VB.net (VS2010), MySQL

I've a client desltop application connecting to my asp.net (vb) website. The desktop app typically sends a request and web app (server) responds to it.

Now, for certain scenarios, I would like website to connect to the client app and sends some data. How do I do it ?

I know client-server app (desktop app to desktop app) but not sure whether this can be done from website to destop app.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SignalR Framework.

From asp.net website : "ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events), grouping connections, and authorization."

Have a look here for documentation and tutorials : http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: Awesome ! Cheers mate.